# Swift - UIImageView subclass with Gestures -- Translate Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am subclassing UIImageView in Swift and adding Pinch, Pan, Zoom, Rotate and Tap Gestures within it.

I have a basic ViewController with a new "PinchZoomImageView" added as a subview.

Everything is working fine, except the Pan Gesture Translate is slightly off when I change the center of the subclassed view.

```
func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)

    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x, y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self)
}
```

After Panning the image and moving the image around the screen it's bounds is off.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it!

Instead of moving the view by it's center property (view.center) I move it with the view.transform (translating translation.x, translation.y) which acts directly on the view rather than the frame via .center...

func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

```
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view)

    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, translation.x, translation.y)
    }

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self)
}
```